# Redis HashScanAsync no longer available

Tags: redis

I have been searching around and haven't found an answer.  To give context in case it matters I am chasing down an error that may not have anything to do with this but since I'm tracing I'm trying to cover all things that I can think of.  I have a method that was previously at some point using hashscanasync but after updating redis it's no longer available and it has been changed to just hashscan.  Is there an alternative or anything because I want to make sure that this is not causing another issue? The error being reported in logging is "Sequence contains no matching element".

Comment: Which library are you using to connect to Redis? Redis itself doesn't have any command `hashscan` (or async). It's `HSCAN`. Due to the async thing I'm guessing maybe you're using Javascript? If you have the code which is causing that error that would also be helpful.

Comment: I'm referring to RedisCacheClient I will update the question to reflect that and this is from c# from the StackExchange.Redis.Extensions.Core package.  I'm not saying that there is an error, I'm trying to figure out what happened to the async version of hashscan?  I'm tracing another issue and was just wondering if the fact that it's no longer async is causing another error.